# Обработка события onChange для Dropdown

Tags: angular2, primefaces

Где найти примеры кода обработки события `onChange` для `Dropdown` или другого похожего элемента `Primeng`?

Answer (score 0):

Судя по [документации](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/dropdown) что то вроде этого:

```
<p-dropdown (onChange)="dropDownChange()">
```

Компонет

```
@Component({})
class Component {
  dropDownChange() {
    /*код*/
  }
}
```

Comment: В документации говориться о 2 параметрах 
'event.originalEvent: Browser event'
'event.value: Selected option value'.
Куда их вставлять и как с ними работать?

Answer (score 0):

Обработка события onChange производится так

```
<p-dropdown (onChange)="onChangeCity($event)"...></p-dropdown>
...
...
onChangeCity(event){
let changedValue = event.value;
let domEvent = event.originalEvent;
...
}
```